# Samsung Home Theater Wireless usb adapter

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb, drivers, home-theater

I have a Samsung Home Theater that you can install a WLAN USB device into. When installed you will be able to get on the wireless network and view Netfilx, YouTube, Pandora, etc.

There is a firmware update for the Blu-Ray device that the WLAN USB plugs into. In order to get that update installed, I have to copy it to the wlan usb device.

The issue is that each time I insert the usb device into my Windows 7 I'm not able to use it as a storage device.  Windows 7 sees this as a Wireless LAN device and wants to install it for use as a WLAN.

I had no problems updating the file using Windows XP, but I can't see to get it on Windows 7.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Model home theater?  Model of the WLAN USB device that you have?